# Displaying Output on the Console Issue

Tags: c++, mfc, console

I am working in a MFC application which runs in both GUI mode and user can run from command prompt.  In GUI mode I work fine. But in command prompt mode, I used printf() to display the error, but nothing comes in the command prompt. To solve this I got the function AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) to display the content to the console. But the output is not sterilized i.e. if I run the application in the command line the out put will look like bellow

```
G:\Bin\conTest\Debug>conTest.exe

G:\Bin\conTest\Debug>This is test comment
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But I want the output to be like bellow

```
G:\Bin\conTest\Debug>conTest.exe

This is test comment
Press any key to continue . . .

G:\Bin\conTest\Debug>
```

Please help me to solve the problem, 
Bellow is the code snippet

```
DWORD written;

if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
{
out = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
}

CString dump = "This is test comment\n";
WriteConsole (out, (LPCTSTR) dump, dump.GetLength(), &written, 0);

system("pause"); 
FreeConsole();
```

Comment: I'd guess the application puts itself as a background process or does the Microsoft equivalent of a fork at some point. Does the next input prompt show up as soon as you start up the application? I've seen this happen a lot when I start up an application as a background process on Linux.

Comment: yes the input prompt shows as soon as application start up.

Answer (score 0):

Use this string instead:

```
CString dump = "\n\nThis is test comment\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fix your issue:

Go to Project>Project Properties>Linker>System and in the right pane, set **SubSystems** option to **Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)**